# how to display different content in the view, while several app launch

Tags: ios, swift, launching-application

the problem that I have is, I got table view with several cells in, what I want is, if the app starts the first time the content of the cell should have the text "The cell have no content". After I prepare the cell, it changes the text "The cell have some articles" and saves everything via core data.
If I run the app again, the cell shows the right content, what I want to now is, how to change the text for the first app launch.

Comment: You can use NSUserDefaults to achieve this.

Comment: Did it works when the cell have different content each time the app launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fetch data from the `fetchedResultsController`. If the `fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count` returns 0 then display an empty `label` showing "No content available", otherwise display the data from the `fetchedResultsController` in your `viewController`. If you have any other issue regarding the answer, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thank you for the great idea,

Comment: Now I'm frustrated on the next thing, I create own class for the prototype cell, drag a label in it to present informations and create a outlet for the label. How can I access the cell's label? I used simple declaration:             let cell = MyCell(), cell.label.text = "Several Content", but it don't works. What I now is, that I should use the corresponding IndexPaths, because each cell have different content after launching, but no idea how to make it in the praxis.

Comment: I didn't understand your another problem,it will be better if you post that question in Stack Overflow and send me the link of the same